# fullPage.js won't scroll

Tags: scroll, fullpage.js

I'm surprised I couldn't find the answer to this problem before. I tried to incorporate the fullpage plugin into my site and basically disabled the scrolling function. It is stuck on the first section. I tried to make a simplified version, cutting everything to the bone, same issue.

in the head section...

```
<link href="css/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.fullPage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.fullpage();
});
</script>
```

In the body section...

```
<body>
<header class="section">
    <div><h1>A</h1></div>
</header>
<main>
    <section class="section">
        <div><h1>B</h1></div>
</section>
<section class="section">
    <div><h1>C</h1></div>
</section>
</main>
</body>
```

What's going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not following the required structure for the plugin.
Your `class="section"` elements should be at the same level as pointed out [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js). You can not have a section inside `<main>`. It should be at the same level.

```
<div class="section">Some section</div>
<div class="section">Some section</div>
<div class="section">Some section</div>
<div class="section">Some section</div>
```

Also, if you are using the last version of the plugin, you should use a wrap for all the sections and use it also at the initialization:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

Initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage();
});
```